# React Hook "useTranslation" cannot be called in a class component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, i18next, react-i18next

I want to make it possible on my site to work in several languages
The problem is that creating a button to switch the language will cause problems for me please help!!!

I have a problem with i18next.
I want create button for switch languages

Here you can see my source code.

its my source code:

```
export default class Navibar extends Component {
render() {
  // Lang paramertrs
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const changeLanguage = (lang) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
  };


  

      return (
        <div className="navibar">
          <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="primary" variant="dark">
            <Navbar fixed="top" />
            <Navbar.Brand id="pad-laft">I House</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
              <Nav className="">
                <NavLink className="text-light">
                  <Link className="btn-header" to="/">
                    <HomeOutlined className="icon-header" /> {t("navibar.home")}
                    {/*  */}
                  </Link>
                </NavLink>

                <NavLink className="text-light">
                  <Link className="btn-header" to="/about">
                    <FileTextOutlined className="icon-header" /> biz haqimizda
                  </Link>
                </NavLink>

                <NavLink className="text-light">
                  <Link className="btn-header" to="/courses">
                    <TeamOutlined className="icon-header" /> kurslar
                  </Link>
                </NavLink>

                <NavLink className="text-light">
                  <Link className="btn-header" to="/faq">
                    <QuestionCircleOutlined className="icon-header" /> faq
                  </Link>
                </NavLink>

                <NavLink className="text-light">
                  <Link className="btn-header" to="/contacts">
                    <PhoneOutlined className="icon-header" /> aloqa
                  </Link>
                </NavLink>

                <button onClick={() => changeLanguage("uz")}>uz.....</button>
                <button onClick={() => changeLanguage("ru")}>ru.....</button>

              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Navbar>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

I will throw off the photo that shows the problem on the browser:

[image: Its image on browser]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use hooks inside the class component. You will have to convert `Navibar` component into the functional component.

Also, take a look at the following rules on react hooks.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using hook try import

import i18n from 'i18next';